# Aromatic and aliphatic amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

Is benzylamine $\ce{C6H5CH2NH2}$ an aromatic or aliphatic amine? I've tried searching for it however different sources have conflicting information.

Answer (score 3):

The nitrogen is bound to a benzyl group, so it would most aptly be classified as a [benzylic amine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzyl_group#Amine_protection). The benzyl group is a common protecting group for amines, and can be removed via hydrogenation with a palladium catalyst. As for the basicity of the nitrogen, it would be most similar to an aliphatic amine.